# Is there a way to override inherited generation strategy?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I'm extending an entity which doesn't auto generate its id.

I want to 'override' its generation strategy to AUTO in my derived class.

Something like this.

```
@Entity
public class Base {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
      return id;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Extender extends Base {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I try to do it:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Extender column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I understand why this happens, but I need to know if there is a valid way to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible, because you can define primary key only once and GeneratedValue can be only where primary key is defined. And same with words from specification:

> 2.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>   ...  The primary key must be defined exactly once in an entity hierarchy.
>
> 11.1.17 GeneratedValue Annotation
>   ... The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or  mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look correct. If you want to use inheritance you must either

- specify `@javax.persistence.Inheritance` in the base class and choose a strategy how the inheritance is to be mapped (enum `InheritanceType`)
- annotate the class `Base` with `@javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass`

Also take a look at the annotation `@javax.persistence.Transient` which gives you the possibility to define a property in a superclass or super interface without having to specify the mapping there.

I don't like inheritance in the data model at all as developers tend to use the `instanceof` operator which will give unexpected results at runtime if you do not have an actual instance of your entity class but a Hibernate-generated proxy object (in case of lazy loading).

Comment: Specifying `javax.persistence.Inheritance` is not mandatory, default is `SINGLE_TABLE`. I haven't included all the code here please assume that it is correct and works (apart from the @Id part).

Comment: You mean I can specify `@Transient` on my base class id and then further define it in the derived classes ?